# Ubuntu 18.04 crash after upgrading from 17.10

Tags: upgrade

I Have a Desktop Dell Optiplex 330 and just upgraded from 17.10
Now the computer wont even start up. It froze after the firt ubuntu screen. Everything was working perfectly in 17.10 and now I cannot acces the computer. Any ideas how can I get it back?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> after boot up. Then login with your username and password and try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If your installation was interrupted it might solve the problems and then:

```
reboot now
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. The installation was not interrupted, everything went fine to the end. What happens is the after appearing the Ubuntu logo and the 5 white dots, after the first 4 dots become pink and appears the mouse pointer, the computer crash. Get frozen at that screen.

Comment: I can get into the Recovery Mode (pressing Shift at start up, and then going to Advance Options.) How can I find out from there what make the computer to crash?

Comment: Thanks Aman. I already upgraded to 18.04 and it is then that my problem started, crashing at start up. How can I find out wich package is causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot Aman, I tried that, but the command sudo apt-get upgrade doesn't do anything since all the packages are already installed in the upgrade. After booting up something crashes the computer and it freezes when the ubuntu logo appears. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes I can boot ubuntu with networking, but only in protected mode. I cannot boot normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Optiplex 330 workstation I use for testing. It ran Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 17.10, and Ubuntu 18.04 beta2 without any issues. When Ubuntu 18.04 was released I did a clean install and it would boot to the Ubuntu logo screen and stop. To resolve the issue I had to disable Wayland in GDM3.

```
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Change `#WaylandEnable=false` to `WaylandEnable=false` and reboot

Reference: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux